# Find the minimum absolute difference between sum of two sub array in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I have an array with N elements (not sorted). Each element of the array can be any integer (positive or negative). Now I have to partitioned this array in a way that absolute(sum(sub_array1) - sum(sub_array2)) is minimal.

Example:
A = {3, 4, 1, 2, -5}

partition1 = sub_array1 {3}, sub_array2 {4, 1, 2, -5} => abs(3-2) = 1

partition2 = sub_array1 {3, 4}, sub_array2 {1, 2, -5} => abs(7-(-2)) = 9

partition3 = sub_array1 {3, 4, 1}, sub_array2 {2, -5} => abs(8-(-3)) = 11

partition4 = sub_array1 {3, 4, 1, 2}, sub_array2{-5}  => abs(10-(-5)) = 15

Answer = 1

I have achieved the solution with O(N^2), but I want to do it with at least O(Nlog(N)), and without threading (parallel solution).

Comment: Why `O(N^2)`? You have `N-1` different ways for partitioning it, and you don't have to sum up each partition from scratch (so you can do it in `O(N)`).

Comment: Pardon me barak, but I didn't get your point, are you trying to say that I should save the sums done in previous steps ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Calculate the entire sum of each partition only at the beginning. Then, every time you change the partitions, subtract an element from one of them and add it to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in linear time, by observing that the sum of the two partitions is constant:

- Sum up all elements in the array (call this `S`).
- Iterate over the array, computing the partial sum (call this `P_i` at step `i`).
- While iterating, find `i` such that `abs(P_i - (S - P_i))` is minimised.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, multithreading doesn't help with complexity, unless you have an infinite number of threads.

You can do it in O(N). Here's a general direction - loop over the possible partitions (N+1), and calculate each partition from the previous one (in each iteration you move one item from on partition to the other).

Comment: So, you mean to say that I should save the previous sum and use it for next. Am I right ?